# How to convert ACE TAO based VS C++ Project to a DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, exe

I am new to DLLs,
currently. I have vs2019 project created using the following MPC(make project created), also it uses [ACE TAO](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/%7Eschmidt/DOC_ROOT/ACE/docs/ACE-guidelines.html)

[these MPC examples show only exporting class or a function, not the main() entry point](https://cs.iupui.edu/%7Ehilljh/faqs/shared-library.php)

**How to export main() entry point (ACE_TMAIN(int argc, ACE_TCHAR *argv[])) using MPC?**

[here is MPC - make project creater](https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/blob/master/tools/modeling/tests/Messenger/Messenger.mpc)

I did some research on DLLs I found most examples have a class which defines methods and export those functions

But here in these OpenDDS applications, they have entry point function **ACE_TMAIN(int argc, ACE_TCHAR *argv[])** main function which is not a class. how to make DLL for this kind of VS project?

[here is ACE_TMAIN() in the source.cpp](https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/blob/master/tools/modeling/tests/Messenger/publisher.cpp)

```
ACE_TMAIN(int argc, ACE_TCHAR *argv[])
{
 // application
}
```

from the MPC it defines exe name,
I want a DLL for this VS project file, not an exe. the DLL will run using a client application (console applciation)

How to make DLL from this MPC or in VS?

I tried setting output type to DLL did not work.

Comment: I suggest that you could package the entire VS project into a dll. For example, create dll.h and dll.cpp in the project. Define an interface start() in dll.cpp, then copy the content in main to start(), and then set the project output as dll.

Comment: @Barrnet Chou **then copy the content in main to start()** you meant we don't need ACE_TMAIN(){} in order to run the rest of the code? which are acts as the main() in this code? and I can call start() from my console c++ project by including this DLL ?

Comment: According to the information provided, the function `ACE_TMAIN()`  is as an entry function. So, you could try to follow the normal entry function. Of course, you could also learn about [dllmain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain).

Comment: @Barrnet Chou my bad.... I am not exactly sure if ACE_TMAIN() is an entry function... since its act as a main() I assume its an entry function .........

Comment: @Barrnet Chou here they call ACE_TMAIN() as an entry function http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/DOC_ROOT/ACE/docs/ACE-guidelines.html

Comment: @BarrnetChou ACE_TMAIN(int argc, ACE_TCHAR *argv[]) has arguments as well how to deal with these arguments?

Comment: You could try to define these in `start(int argc，ACE_TCHAR * argv [])`.